# How can I stop queue animation jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this function to add or remove products from favorites.
When I add or remove a product from favorites a div pops out with a message.
I have a problem with the queue animation.

Does anyone knows a way to fix this?

```
function addFavorite(code, action) {
    var website = 'http://localhost';
    var cod = code;
    var action = action;
    var $this = $j(this);


    if (action == 'removeFav') {

        $j.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/ajax/handler.favorite.php?action=removeFav',
            data: {
                'cod': cod
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $j('.topMessage').show();
                $j('.topMessage span').html('<img src="' + website + '/assets/loader.gif" alt="loading..">');
                $j('.topMessage span').animate({
                    top: "+=80px",
                }, 500);
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $j('.topMessage span').html(data);
                $j('.topMessage span').delay(3000).animate({
                    top: "-=80px",
                }, 500);
            }

        });

    }

    if (action == 'addFav') {

        $j.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/ajax/handler.favorite.php?action=addFav',
            data: {
                'cod': cod
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $j('.topMessage').show();
                $j('.topMessage span').html('<img src="' + website + '/assets/loader.gif" alt="loading..">');
                $j('.topMessage span').animate({
                    top: "+=80px",
                }, 500);

            },
            success: function(data) {
                $j('.topMessage span').html(data);
                $j('.topMessage span').delay(3000).animate({
                    top: "-=80px",
                }, 500);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:
Create a function to display your messages and animate your div.

```
function displayAddedMessage(message) {
    var span = $j('.topMessage span');
    var addedMessage = span.parent();
    var wrapper = addedMessage.parent();
    addedMessage.css('top', -85).hide();
    if (message) {
        span.html(message);
    }
    var clonedAddedMessage = addedMessage.clone(false);
    addedMessage.remove();
    wrapper.prepend(clonedAddedMessage);
    clonedAddedMessage.show().delay(100).animate({
        top: 10
    }, 500).delay(3500).animate({
        top: -100
    }, 500);
}
```

You can use this function in:

```
function addFavorite(code, action) {
    var website = 'http://localhost';
    var cod = code;
    var action = action;
    var $this = $j(this);



    if (action == 'removeFav') {

        $j.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/ajax/handler.favorite.php?action=removeFav',
            data: {
                'cod': cod
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $j('.topMessage').show();
                displayAddedMessage('<img src="' + website + '/assets/loader.gif" alt="loading..">');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $j('.topMessage span').html(data);
                displayAddedMessage(data);
            }

        });
    }

    if (action == 'addFav') {

        $j.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/ajax/handler.favorite.php?action=addFav',
            data: {
                'cod': cod
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $j('.topMessage').show();
                displayAddedMessage('<img src="' + website + '/assets/loader.gif" alt="loading..">');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $j('.topMessage span').html(data);
                displayAddedMessage(data);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve like this :

```
$j('.topMessage span').stop().animate({
    top: "-=80px",
}, 500);
```

Refer [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Comment: it doesn't work because It has to finish animation and I have a delay

Comment: animation "complete" call back will help you for this.

Comment: Please make jsFiddle, It will help us

Answer (score 0):

hope this will solve your problem

first create a global variable

```
 var isAnimating = false; // a global variable
```

then change your ajax request code with this one

```
    $j.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/ajax/handler.favorite.php?action=removeFav',
        data: {
            'cod': cod
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $j('.topMessage').show();
            $j('.topMessage span').html('<img src="' + website + '/assets/loader.gif" alt="loading..">');
            iF(!isAnimating) { // check animation is not running
                isAnimating = true; 
                $j('.topMessage span').animate({
                    top: "+=80px",
                }, 500);
            }

        },
        success: function(data) {
            $j('.topMessage span').html(data);
            $j('.topMessage span').delay(3000).animate({
                top: "-=80px",
            }, 500, function() {
                isAnimating = false; // this callback will called after animation complete
            });
        }

    });
```

Comment: not working :( , same problem. If I click on multiple fav icons the animation is queueing.If the animation is not completed it should display just a message not the entire animation again.